# How to convert single String containing a comma separated json values into a single json object?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, gson

I am getting some data which is a single string

```
"{"somekey": someValue}, {"someKey2": someValue}, {"someKey3": someValue}"
```

how would I return that as a single json object like this using java libraries?

```
{{"somekey": someValue}, {"someKey2": someValue}, {"someKey3": someValue}}
```

I have been trying to use the ObjectMapper class to read the value into a List but can't convert it.

```
List<String> list = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<String>> () {});
```

I have the option to retrieve the data in an array like this:

```
[{"somekey": someValue}, {"someKey2": someValue}, {"someKey3": someValue}]
```

but I still can't manage to convert it to a single json Object response

Comment: If you can retrieve the data like an array, can't you just convert the array to a string and replace the [] to {} and then cast that string to an object?

Comment: Are you _sure_ that's the actual data? Because if it is, first strip the outer double quotes and then run through your string, counting `{` and `}`, and splitting when you see a comma while at "depth" 0.

Comment: You should read this: "_JSON exists as a string_" from [No, really, what is JSON?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON#no_really_what_is_json) since there is nothing in your question that resembles a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

```
String jsonString = "{"somekey": someValue}, {"someKey2": someValue}, {"someKey3": someValue}"; 
Object object = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Object.class);
```

Try this

Comment: can you just elaborate what and how it does the task

Answer (score -1):

If you have a JSON string that looks as follows:

```
String userJson = "[{'name': 'Alex','id': 1}, "
            + "{'name': 'Brian','id':2}, "
            + "{'name': 'Charles','id': 3}]";
```

And a corresponding POJO that looks as follows:

```
public class User 
{
    private long id;
    private String name;
          
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

You could then use a library GSON to parse the JSON string into an array of User objects:

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
 
User[] userArray = gson.fromJson(userJson, User[].class);
```